# How to loop an array from JSON API

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to loop the array from JSON API in Angular2 but I dont have any idea how?

[image]

I wanted to get the Total Amount of the Subtotals. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: plenty of options for iterating through in typescript;  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html.  for example, create a new property for the total, then use `for..of` to iterate through each object and add each `cart_subtotal` to the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try it**, I hope, it will help you

```
totalAmount:number = 0;
for(let i=0;i<this.data.length;i++){
    totalAmount = totalAmount  + this.data[i].cart_subtotal;
}
```

If `cart_subtotal` gives string value then use:

```
totalAmount = totalAmount  + parseInt(this.data[i].cart_subtotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `*ngFor` directive. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor) is a link to the official docs that show how to use the `*ngFor` directive. In your case you need to use properties from the object, so I have added properties to the example below that is from the Angular documentation. You can access the properties of each individual object using standard dot notation.

**From the Documentation**

```js
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        {{ hero.firstName }} {{ hero.lastName }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

So if you are just wanting to add up all of the `cart_subtotals` then you need to declare a property within your component and then update the `grandTotal` anytime a new object is added to the array. I don't know how you are adding items to the array, but the portion labeled accordingly below needs to be carried out every time a new item is added. It also looks like your subtotals are in the form of strings so you'll need to parse them before you can do any mathematical operations on them.

```js
// Declare in your component
private grandTotal: number = 0;

// Run anytime an object is added to the array.
updateGrandTotal() {
    // Instantiate a temporary new grand total variable.
    let newGrandTotal = 0;
    // Iterate over each cart item.
    this.carts.forEach(_Cart => {
        // Add the current cart subtotal to the new grand total.
        newGrandTotal = newGrandTotal + parseInt(_Cart.cart_subtotal)
    })
    // Save the New GrandTotal to the Grand Total Property.
    this.grandTotal = newGrandTotal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response sir, what I wanted to happen sir is I want to show it in my ts sir. I can do it. What I did is like this: this.price = this.data[0].cart_subtotal; I want to loop the data[0] so that I dont have to do it one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure `*ngFor` is what the OP is looking for; they are trying to total the values of the iterated items, which would be done in the typescript, not the HTML.  I do agree that it doesn't strike me as a well researched question, which is why I only made a comment and didn't provide an official answer.

Comment: thanks @Claies, that is how exactly wanted to happen

Comment: I see, how are the objects being injected into the array? Being that you are using Angular I am sure you are adding them asynchronously somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better(more modern) way to do this would be to use a reduce function, since summing is the canonical example for a reduce function. You could do something like this:

```
let sum = ((items, prop) => {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + b.prop;
    }, 0)
})

let sum = sum(cartInfo, 'cart_subtotal')
```

This is not a tested/working example, but should give you a good idea of how to implement this sort of behavior in a functional and modern way :)